# Python -user input the data value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program in Python that generate a random numbers

```
 import random
num = [x for x in range(1000)]
random.shuffle(num)
num
```

but then I decide to let the user enter the size/ max number like the following:

```
    import random
xx= input("please Enter the max")
xx= int(xx)
num = [x for x in range(xx)]
random.shuffle(num)
num
```

could you please tell me how can i deal with it?

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is exactly? What is not working to your expectations?

Comment: Assuming your indentation isn't off, what isnt working about your code?

Comment: Deal with what? BTW- you are not generating random numbers at all,  you just randomizing the order of know numbers

Comment: the problem is that  range(xx) doesn't read from input the entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake, i just added print(nums) to the code and i got the output

```
 import random
xx= input("please Enter the max")
xx= int(xx)
num = [x for x in range(xx)]
random.shuffle(num)
print(nums)
```